Given OpenJDK's imminent deprecation for removal of sun.misc.Unsafe, is there an alternative to accessing an object's mark word or generation age?
I help maintain a Java immutable collections library. One critical optimization we do is deduplicating internal structures of our collections during equality checks when the internal structures are considered value equal but are not the same object. In order to do this, a choice over which internal structure to keep and which one to replace is made. This decision is made based on the following two factors:

Prefer the object with the older generational age, if available

This is particularly effective given the workloads align very well with the generational hypothesis (and we always choose to use a generational GC)


Otherwise, prefer the object with the lower i-hash

And before anyone asks, we know that a lower i-hash doesn't mean created earlier. We only care about the fact it creates a mostly sorta global ordering of objects, the meaning of the ordering is inconsequential.



For JVM's running the G1 or CMS GCs we use sun.misc.Unsafe to access the object's mark word and then get the object's generational age. Given the imminent deprecation for removal of sun.misc.Unsafe, we are wondering if there alternatives to accessing an object's age (without going to jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe)
We have done a fair amount of research, but we have found no solutions so far other than options that are less supported than before.

What if you assume the age of all objects is 0?

@apangin Then the optimization would only use the i-hash which is less effective. Often the way these collections are used means there will be an equality check between a long lived instance of a collection and a just created instance of the same collection and this allows for the just created collection to essentially use no space (and be collected quickly) and do many forms of comparison near instantly, irrespective of the collections size.

I understand your intention. I mean, what is the actual (measured) effect of not using any age information in a typical application, especially with new JDKs (21+)?

It’s funny that you are worrying now about the “deprecated, for removal” status, given that Unsafe never was officially supported to begin with and it’s removal announced (and repeatedly delayed) for at least a decade. I’m still not sure what will come first, the actual removal of Unsafe or the introduction of value types with built-in deduplication. Only when the former happens significantly earlier than the latter, it’s necessary to find alternatives to your current solution, but it’s quite possible that none will exist. Like apangin, I’m interested in actual numbers regarding performance…

@Holger Please read this with only a tone of respect. It has nothing to do with whether or not it was officially supported, it was available, it was and still is commonly used, and it solved problems people needed to solve. I'm worrying now because we have a use case for Unsafe that was never captured by a "safe" API (something the JVM maintainers said they would do before removing features from Unsafe), and really what we are using Unsafe for isn't even unsafe, just obscure.

On the note of performance numbers, I don't have them. I'm not the one who has historically gathered that, but on a conceptual level the amount of waisted computation that will occur due to random pollution of a newly created object over an older one means continued wasted computation for the entire lifetime of the program instead of eliminating it at the start. This isn’t something that modern concurrent collectors can solve, nor value classes, due to their equality specification.

I understand the curiosity and not wanting to take an optimization on faith, but this question isn’t about whether the age optimization is effective, it is if there is a known way to access object’s age as discovered by GCs or to access the mark word of an object (or even plans to make it available)

Considering that 1) not every GC algorithm maintains an age counter and it’s not even clear whether future JVM version will ship with any GC algorithm maintaining a counter and 2) you can not prove that the access to the counter has any actual benefit, what answer do you expect regarding an API to access the counter?


That's why I specified in the question that we only use generational GCs. The following GCs are only generational or have a generational mode [Serial, Parallel, CMS, G1, ZGC (mode), Shenandoah (mode)] both ones that support it in a mode will move to generational as the default mode. That is every collector currently supported in Hotspot and all of them maintain age for objects in one way or another that can be represented as an integer.



I'm not expecting anyone to go out of their way to create an API to solve this without good numbers and cause (and I am perfectly capable of making a proposal to the hotspot maintainers and doing the work myself), I just wanted to ask if someone else somehow new of a way to achieve this. I don’t expect a positive result, but I figured I’d put the question out there. (I can also get numbers; I just won’t have them for a few days and didn’t think I’d need them to ask)


Unsafe is deprecated for removal not so much because it is "unsafe", but because it is often abused by library developers to break encapsulation of JVM internals - exactly what you are trying to do. Such "optimizations" can cause issues with JDK updates (e.g., Project Lilliput significantly changes the layout of object header) and may also degrade performance instead of improving it (e.g., prevent scalar replacement).
